# Pronunciation of “have to” as “haf to”

Tags: american-english, phonetics

I’m a young speaker from Chicago. A colloquial phrase I hear and say often is “I have to _,” indicating an obligation to do something. However, I’ve noticed that “have” is pronounced in a nonstandard way in this phrase, essentially equivalent to the word “half.” For example, I might pronounce the phrase like this:

[hæf tʊu̯] if it doesn’t precede a stressed word or [hæf tə] if it does, with stress on the first word and no aspiration in the second. The important part is the [f].

I wonder if there is an explanation for the devoicing of the /v/ in this phrase. One idea might be to distinguish it phonologically from the similar phrase “have two” as in “I have two pet narwhals,” which would also differ in terms of stress and aspiration.

I also wonder if there are any other situations in which /v/ might be devoiced.

Finally, I am curious about the regional distribution of this phenomenon, its prevalence within different age groups, and the time around which it might have begun.

Comment: Other verb phrases with devoicing in American English are *supposed to* and *used to*, although in these it's a /d/ that's devoiced.

Comment: This is a normal pronunciation -- fully expected in American English and probably in other dialects.  This occurs simply because the speaker doesn't want to strain to pronounce "have".

Comment: I think we say *haf to* or *hafta* because it's easier. I wouldn't call it "nonstandard" — that *is* how we say it.

Comment: We use all these pronunciations in casual speech in the UK too.

Comment: @HotLicks In other words, it's slovenly speech where the speaker can't be bothered to pronounce the words properly.

Comment: @PeterJennings -- No, it's normal speech, where the speaker is not trying to sound hoity-toity.

Answer (score 1):

The letter is different from the sound.

Devoicing occurs.

One thing expedient to note is how voiceless it sounds. Though, there is no difference in the articulation of /f/ and /v/ as the upper teeth articulates with the lower lip; there is no vibration occurrence in the vocal chord.

Comment: Don't be so certain that no speaker makes any difference in the articulation when pronouncing their /f/ and /v/ and that voicing alone separates them. The teeth may land in a slightly different place on the lip for *vat* than they do in *fat*. Typically /v/ comes out with more rounding, and this is reflected in lip movement.